# Consequence of tightness of sequence of random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ a tight sequence of random variable. In my lecture I have

> **Proposition** For all subsequence $(X_{n_k})$ there is a subsequence $(X_{n_{k_j}})$ and a random variable $X$ s.t. $$X_{n_{k_j}}\Rightarrow X.$$

**Question :** As written, it looks that $X$ depend on the subsequence, i.e. if we change the subsequence, then we don't have the same $X$. Shouldn't the proposition be :

There is $X$ s.t. for all subsequence $(X_{n_k})$ there is a further subsequence $(X_{n_{k_j}})$ s.t. $X_{n_{k_j}}\Rightarrow X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your statement is not correct. If $X$ and $Y$ are two different random variables and $X_n=X$ for $n$ even , $X_n=Y$ for $n$ odd then $(X_n)$ is tight but your conclusion clearly fails in this case.

Comment: very good counter example ! thanks